# image related info showing while image centered when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fade

I have the following problem:

I want image related captions in a div to show up while scrolling through my tumblr blog. So far I embedded the following code and managed to get it work:

script I used:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RHys/145/)**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        var pos = $('#captionposition').offset();
        $('.post').each(function () {
            if (pos.top >= $(this).offset().top && pos.top <= $(this).next().offset().top) {
                $('#captionposition').html($(this).find('.tags').text()); //or any other way you want to get the date
                return; //break the loop
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
    });

})
```

**[My blog](http://benniejuliangay1.tumblr.com/)**

I am not sure how exactly "top" is defined, but it turned out being quite confusing for the viewer as there's no "pause" inbetween the captions and the div seems to pop up eventhough the image is not even fully visible in the window. Plus if two or even more images show up at the same time it's uncertain to which the info belongs.

What would I aim for?

I would love to have the div with the informations only visible for the image fully centered. center +/- 10% would be enough I guess (but would like to play around with this if possible). And a rather smooth fade in/out animation would be great as well.

I am super thankful in advance if anybody can help me!

original code:

```
{block:Photo}


            <li class="post photo">

                    <ul class="post-data">
                        {block:IfPhotoIconImage}<li class="icon"></li>{/block:IfPhotoIconImage}
                        <li class="info"></li>
                    </ul>

                <div class="post-content">
                    <div class="content-img-wrapper">{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-1280}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>{LinkCloseTag}</div>
                    {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
                    </div>

                    {block:HasTags}
                    <ul class="tags" style="display: none;">
                        {block:Tags}
                        <li><a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>   
                        {/block:Tags}
                    </ul>
                    {/block:HasTags}                        

            </li>


            {/block:Photo}

<div id='captionposition'></div>
```

okay, so this is what worked well for me (check iris post for further explanations):

```
$(window).load(function () {

var window_center = $(window).height()/2;
var threshold = 0;

    $(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        //var pos = $('#captionposition').offset();

        $('.post').each(function () {
        var post_center = $(this).height()/2 + $(this).offset().top;

            if (post_center + threshold < window_center + scroll ||
                post_center - threshold < window_center + scroll) {

            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
                $('.post').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $( "#captionposition" ).hide();
                $( "#captionposition").html($(this).find('.caption').text());  
                $( "#captionposition" ).fadeIn('slow');

            }
                return; //break the loop
            }

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
    });

})

</script>
```

Comment: First of all, I see a Syntax error in your blog, **var pos = $('#captionposition').offset(); Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined**, and for the smooth fade in/out animation. I would use $(element).hide(); $(element).html(newhtml); $(element).fadeIn('slow'); [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6RHys/154/). Looks like you fixed the error while I was writting this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I made a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6RHys/160/) that could help you.

```
$(window).load(function () {
var window_center = $(window).height()/2;
var threshold = 0;
$(window).on("scroll resize", function () {
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('.post').each(function () {
        var post_center = $(this).height()/2 + $(this).offset().top;
        if (post_center + threshold < window_center + scroll ||
            post_center - threshold < window_center + scroll){
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
                $('.post').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('#captionposition').hide();
                var newDescr = $(this).find('.tags');
                $('#captionposition').html(newDescr.html());    
                $('#captionposition').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).trigger('scroll'); // init the value
});
});
```

Things to know:

1. I used $(window).scrollTop() as reference, so we know how much it's    scrolled.
2. Added a Threshold variable, to set the +/- percent you wanted.
3. The scripts calculates the center of window and center of each .post.

Comment: thank you very much iris. I have trouble implementing it, but a friend will help me tomorrow morning.

Comment: You are welcome. If you post your blog code related to the issue maybe we can help exactly with what you need.

Comment: Find the original code above. You did remove the part that reads the tags and put them in the div. I tried to recombine them, but I cannot make sense of it at all. Any advice, help? (I am actually only cormfortable in html/css) thanks Iris

Comment: Hi Bennie, I've editted my post to fit your new requierements. I think it should do the trick. Just remember to play with the **threshold** variable for your desired behaviour.

Comment: hey, just because I'm curious: would it be hard to set the tame of fade in to "3 (x) seconds after scroll bar rest"? say you stop scrolling and it takes a certain amount of time for the elements to appear again?

Comment: I'm glad that it's working. About the time to fade in and fade out, it's possible of course. You only have to replace the 'slow' parameter to the miliseconds you want it to take. **.fadeIn(4000);** will be 4 seconds. More info about this here: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/